# Show a text at the particular X, Y, Z position in a 3d model in Android

Tags: android, 3d, annotations, 3d-rendering

I'm able render a 3d model (from STL, OBJ or DAE file) in an Android app using [this engine](https://github.com/andresoviedo/android-3D-model-viewer/). Now I need help to show a text at the particular X, Y, Z position on it.

Comment: you have got any solution for this?

Comment: No, Not yet Adil. Please let me know if you find any